# Subversion any pre lock hook causes unlock to fail

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

I have installed VisualSVN Server on Windows XP. (Authentication method - Basic Windows authentication). I edited the `pre-lock.cmd` script and put a comment line, `REM do nothing`.

Next I tried to get a lock on a file. Everything works great until this point!

Then I try to release the lock and get the following error `Server sent unexpected return value (400 Bad Request) in response to UNLOCK`.

Please note I do not have any pre/post unlock scripts in place. I am using the TortoiseSVN client. I have tried the lock/unlock routine without the pre-lock hook and it works fine.

Any insight on why this must be happening will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Subversion 1.6 the output of a pre-lock script is important.  a .bat file echo's by default, so every command is sent to the output which will cause problems.

Have as the first line
@echo off

and things should go much better

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a line like

```
exit 0
```

in your pre-lock.bat script (not sure if *.cmd scripts work, but *.bat files do).

Also the "bad request" error could be because a firewall/router/virus scanner doesn't allow (or know) DAV requests.